# PostgreSQL add outcome of query as column to table "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with boat positions. I am trying to find the the closest waterway to these data points and add the name of this waterway in a new column. I have tried to realize this with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE boat_positions 
ADD COLUMN wayname VARCHAR;

UPDATE boat_positions SET wayname = (SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) b.name 
FROM public."boat_positions" a, public."waterways" b
WHERE b.geom && ST_Expand(a.geom, 100)
ORDER BY a, ST_Distance(b.geom, a.geom) ASC);
```

With this I run into the error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

I understand why this is but I don't have the SQL skills to solve it in a good way. I came up with an indirect solution by first creating a new table and then combining it with the original, as below:

```
CREATE TABLE wayname AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a.index, b.name 
FROM public."boat_positions" a, public."waterways" b
WHERE b.geom && ST_Expand(a.geom, 100)
ORDER BY a, ST_Distance(b.geom, a.geom) ASC;

ALTER TABLE boat_positions 
ADD COLUMN wayname VARCHAR;

UPDATE boat_positions AS a
SET wayname = (SELECT w.name FROM wayname AS b
WHERE a.index=b.index)
```

However, this solution takes time and memory. Is there better way to do this directly?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

You must return only 1 record, the nearest one, by specifying a `limit 1` clause.

Using the `<->` operator, the query can make use of the spatial index.

```sql
UPDATE boat_positions 
SET wayname = 
 (
    SELECT b.name
    FROM waterways AS b
    WHERE b.geom && ST_Expand(boat_positions.geom, 100)
    ORDER BY boat_positions.geom <-> b.geom
    LIMIT 1 
 );
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick! Thanks a lot!